# How to set the toCat in the DualListField

Tags: java, gxt

Can somebody help me?
I want to display the old selected categories in the side where the DualListField selected items should be.
Whenever I click the column for the categories this lines of codes of the DualListField will show.

```
VerticalLayoutContainer vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
        vlc.setWidth(350);
        add(vlc);

        ListStore<Category> fromCat = new ListStore<Category>(catProp.IDCategory());
        fromCat.addAll(list);
        toCat = new ListStore<Category>(catProp.IDCategory());
        field = new DualListField<Category, String>(fromCat, toCat, catProp.strName(), new TextCell());
        field.addValidator(new EmptyValidator<List<Category>>());
        field.setEnableDnd(true);
        field.setWidth(300);
```

But before that, the grid in the categories already had an old selected items which I want them to be in the toCat.  How would that be possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just add the values to toCat?

Comment: @udeleng I already tried this line of code
toCat.addAll(properties.categories());
but it doesn't work because properties came from a different class which is the UserRights. and my DualListField came from Categories

Comment: Well I'm serious. I really need help. Does anyone here have any idea???